# Authentication-Info header for Bearer (JWT) Auth Scheme

Tags: http, authentication, jwt, restful-authentication, bearer-token

I am using JWT Bearer authentication scheme in a REST api. For returning jwt token to client after successful authentication, currently i am using access token response in body as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#page-10

```
{
   "access_token":"mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA"
 }
```

But need to return token in other HTTP request too like signup where body is already present.
So, was thinking of using ["Authentication-Info"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7615#page-3) header for it. But [Bearer Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) does not specify "Authentication-Info" header anywhere. Should i use Authentication-Info header for returning jwt token?

Not using OAuth 2.0, just JWT.

Comment: "Not using OAuth 2.0, just JWT." so you are not therefore bound to follow the OAuth RFC. You may, and I would recommend, using `Authentication-Info` as the means to deliver the token.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there might be correct for OAuth 2.0, but for ordinary JWT it's much simpler. When you use ordinary self-made JWT, the client will put the token on an HTTP header called *Authorization*. The value of the header is something like this

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

The header field could be called something else too. The server and client has to agree on the name. *Authorization* is just the most common name.

The server will usually issue the token by responding to the POST request on the login endpoint. The token can be a part of the response body when the login is successful. The client will store the token and send the token with every request by using the header above. You can forget everything that has to do with access token and refresh token. When using "ordinary" basic JWT you will only have one token, and that is the value after Bearer.

I don't see any reason to issue a token when the user is signing up. They can get it when they log in after signing up.

I would recommend you to read [this](https://jwt.io/introduction/) over the RFCs for OAuth if you're just implementing ordinary authentication.

Comment: I am returning token on signup because business requirement is to login user immediately after signup, no login screen should be there.

Comment: I am using "Authorization" header to send token in each request, but the question is how to return the token to client in the login request.

Comment: When the client sends a post request, the server also has to respond with a response. Typically with status code 200 and message: { success: true }, or something similar. You can append the token to this request. [This](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52) blog post has an example (**AuthController.js**). It's for Node, but the concept is the same in all languages and frameworks. The token can also be sent as a response on the register endpoint.

Comment: I have created REST Api. So, appending token in user object response does not seem appropriate.